# Reusable content across site collection for rich text editor

Tags: site-collection, rich-text, reusable

Is it possible to have access to the root site collection's Reusable Content list in all its web sites? If not, how do you add the list to a web site? I'm trying to put some common UI elements in this list for editors to drop into multiline rich text fields. However, the item is greyed out and says it's disabled. Anyone know how you enable it in these fields? I have admin privileges to the site collection. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe reusable content list is created at root web only when you enable publishing infrastructure or start with publishing site template. You can use it in all sub sites under site collection. To use it in rich text field of sharepoint site, the publishing features must be enabled at sub sites level too.

A similar question is answered here http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=676af157%2D7d96%2D4e15%2Da987%2D54b8a3e4d948&ID=77

Also make sure the rich text field you have is "full HTML with Formatting and constraints of publishing"

Comment: Thanks, Ashish. I think the missing piece is the "full HTML with Formatting and constraints of publishing". I'll check on that and see.